Mahram of Married Slave In case of Hajj & Umrah
Who is the Mahram of Married Slave Women when it comes to her performing Hajj or Umrah as per Fuqaha? Can A Married Slave women perform Hajj and Umrah along with her Master and can the Master become or be considered Mahram for Hajj or Umrah if her husband due to some reason is unable to perform Umrah or Hajj with her?
I prefer to especially know the Ahkaam From Hanbali Madhab

Hajj is not due on slaves - as Hajj requires having the means to perform it and slaves do not have these means as they do not own property and are preoccupied due to the commitment to their owners.
For general travel purposes it is stated in Mataalib Ooli al-Nuha that the husband of a slave woman can not travel with her without the permission of her master, as her traveling would deprive the the master from his right to service during the day. And the master can not travel with her without the permission of the husband since it would deprive the husband from his martial rights during the night. This implies that she can travel with either one of them if the other one waives his right.
